# Docker swarm get deployment status

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

After running `docker stack deploy` to deploy some services to swarm is there a way to programmatically test if all containers started correctly?

The purpose would be to verify in a staging CI/CD pipeline that the containers are actually running and didn't fail on startup. Restart is disabled via `restart_policy`.

I was looking at `docker stack services`, is the `replicas` column useful for this purpose?

```
$ docker stack services --format "{{.ID}} {{.Replicas}}" my-stack-name
lxoksqmag0qb 0/1
ovqqnya8ato4 0/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in CI/CD I see everyone using docker or docker-compose. A container runs the same in docker as it does docker swarm with respects to "does this container work by itself as intended".

That being said, if you still wanted to do integration testing in a multi-tier solution with swarm, you could do various things in automation. Note this would all be done on a single node swarm to make testing easier (docker events doesn't pull node events from all nodes, so tracking a single node is much easier for ci/cd):

1. Have something monitoring [docker events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/), e.g. `docker events -f service=<service-name>` to ensure containers aren't dying.
2. *always* have healthchecks in your containers. They are the #1 way to ensure your app is healthy (at the container level) and you'll see them succeed or fail in `docker events`. You can put them in [Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), [service create commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/), and [stack/compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). [Here's some great examples](https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck).
3. You could attach another container to the same network to test your services remotely 1-by-1 using tasks. with reverse DNS. This will avoid the VIP and let you talk to a specific replica(s).
4. You might get some stuff out of `docker inspect <service-id or task-id>`

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. Do you happen to have experience with kubernetes? If yes, how does it differ to docker swarm when verifying that deploys actually succeed. Does it have more built-in tools to do that or is it still rather manual and requires similar steps to what you've described here.

Comment: Yes Kubernetes has different tools and API's. I recommend asking it as a new SO question, not a comment on a Swarm one.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are ways to do it, but it's manual and you'd have to be pretty comfortable with docker cli. Docker does not provide an easy built-in way to verify that `docker stack deploy` succeeded. [There is an open issue about it](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/373).

Fortunately for us, community has created a few tools that implement docker's shortcomings in this regard. Some of the most notable ones:

- https://github.com/issuu/sure-deploy
- https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-stack-wait
- https://github.com/ubirak/docker-php

Issuu, authors of [sure-deploy](https://github.com/issuu/sure-deploy), have [a very good article describing this issue](https://engineering.issuu.com/2018/09/12/confident-deployments).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to use `docker service scale` - it will not return until service is converged to specified amount of replicas or will timeout.

```sh
export STACK=devstack # swarm stack name
export SERVICE_APP=yourservice # service name
export SCALE_APP=2 # desired amount of replicas

docker stack deploy $STACK --with-registry-auth
docker service scale ${STACK}_${SERVICE_APP}=${SCALE_APP}
```

One drawback of that method is that you need to provide service names and their replica counts (but these can be extracted from compose spec file using `jq`).

Also, in my use case I had to specify timeout by prepending `timeout` command, i.e. `timeout 60 docker service scale`, because `docker service scale` was waiting its own timeout even if some containers failed, which could potentially slow down continuous delivery pipelines

##### References

[Docker CLI: docker service scale](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/)

[jq - command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

[GNU Coreutils: timeout command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation)

Comment: you can also just update stack (whitout options), to not need to specify the scale : ```docker service update STACK_SERVICENAME```

Answer (score -1):

you can call this for every service. it returns when converged. (all ok)

```
docker service update STACK_SERVICENAME
```